# Height of a optional tree

Tags: c++, tree, height

I need to calculate the height of an optinal (NOt AVL, binary) tree.
For input I receive n integer positive number: parent(0), parent(1), ... parent(n-1).
Here parent(i) is a parent of node i. If parent(i) == -1 that i is the root of the tree.
It is guaranteed that the sequence has only one root and presets a tree.
Limitation: 1 <= n <= 1e5
Example:
Input

```
5
4 -1 4 1 1
Output
3

 1
/ \
3  4
   /\
   0 2
```

My program on C++ works but it looks like that the algorhythm is not optimal. The program is verified automatically
and one of the test failed with error "Time limit exceeded".
Could you advice me, please, on how I can optimize the program?

```
#include "iostream"

int tree[10000];
int n = 0;

int Height(int parent);

int main ()
{
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> tree[i];
    }

    std::cout << Height(-1) - 1;
    return 0;
}

int Height(int parent)
{
    int height = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (tree[i] == parent)
        {
            height = std::max(height, 1 + Height(i));
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

Comment: I'd say store int childs[10000][2]; and int root; while reading from file;  height(i) = 1 + max(height(childs[i][0], height(childs[i][1]); and answer is height(root), so you will eliminate need to iterate via array in search of parent

Comment: What is the difference between childs[i][0] and childs[i][1]?

Comment: no difference at all, in this case only parent-child relation are important, (existence or absence of child nodes). (if there are no child nodes, you store new child node with index 0, if there is child node, you store with index 1)

Comment: But I can not get to know if child exists or not till I recieve all the sequence.   And I need to iterate via array anyway...

Comment: You need to iterate through file while reading it, there is no need to iterate through array ! You call height of root, height of node calls height of its child nodes. Your code, on other hand, iterate through array on each recursive call of height(). (10k comparision and increments per call you can avoid)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has already been asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162079/height-of-a-general-tree-in-c, which is a better place for such questions.

Comment: Yes, I have moved the question to CODEREVIEW.